# Cannot import from a git submodule

Tags: python, git, git-submodules

I'm having difficulties making a git submodule work.

I have a project `ProjectA` that basically is a `mainA.py` file and a subfolder with library files:
The `mainA.py` contains a `MainClass` that is basically what should be called, and `Libraries` just contain scripts and classes for computations.

```
ProjectA/
    Libraries/
        __init__.py
        library1.py
        library2.py
    __init__.py
    mainA.py
```

In `mainA.py` I just do something like:

```
# content of mainA.py
from Libraries.library1 import ClassA, ClassB

class MainClass:
    # do stuff

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainClass()
```

This just works fine, but I have now a `ProjectB` that needs to use the `MainClass` from `ProjectA`, so I decided to put `ProjectA` as a git submodule of `ProjectB`

```
git submodule add ProjectA_git_url

ProjectB/
    ProjectA/
    mainB.py
    .gitmodules
```

However now in `mainB.py` I'm trying to import `MainClass` from `projectA`.

```
# content of mainB.py
from ProjectA.mainA import MainClass

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Libraries'
```

I think this happens because now `Libraries` is no longer hanging from the root directory, but inside the submodule `ProjectA`, so when `mainA.py` does:

```
from Libraries.library1 import ClassA, ClassB
```

The system cannot find `Libraries`.
If I change `mainA.py` to do:

```
from ProjectA.Libraries.library1 import ClassA, ClassB
```

Then it works, but of course I don't want to change anything insise `ProjectA`, it is just a Project that should work either standalone or as a submodule of another project

What am I doing wrong? Is there a way to import `MainClass` from `mainA.py` when `ProjectA` is a submodule?

Comment: Well, you *do* have a `ProjectA` directory... python does not simply ignore that directory level because it checks that it is a git submodule. Your submodule should have `Libraries` as top level directory to make this work. Period. If you can't do this then don't use a git submodule...

Comment: Well, python won't ignore it, but maybe there's a way that git submodule adds the submodules in the python path or system path, so the submodules can see themselves in the root directory, or some similar solution. I think my case is a common one and I'm wondering if git submodules already has something to handle that

Comment: Try `from .Libraries.library1 import ClassA, ClassB` **so with a . before `Libraries`**.

Comment: The problem you are having here is that when importing something from `mainA` you need relative imports in `mainA` (so `from .Libraries.`...), where as you need absolute import (so `from Libraries.`...) if `mainA` is run as a script. Basically, given the current structure, the solution to one mode of use breaks the other. So, consider restructuring things by splitting up `mainA` in a module and in a script part. ...now this became actually more of an answer than a comment...

Answer (score -1):

`git` is a **development** tool; you use it during development but not deployment. `pip` is a deployment tool; during development you use it to install necessary libraries; during deployment your users use it to install your package with dependencies.

Use submodules when you need something from a remote repository in your **development** environment. For example, if said remote repository contains Makefile(s) or other non-python files that you need and that usually aren't installed with `pip`.

That is, in your case you shouldn't make `ProjectA` a submodule of `ProjectB`, you should make `ProjectA` a Python dependency. Create packages for `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` and install them separately but allow `ProjectB` to import from `ProjectA`.

Dependencies are declared in `setup.py` or `requirements.txt`.

That said, if you insist on using submodules: either you have to manipulate `sys.path` yourself or you do relative import in `mainA.py`:

```
from .Libraries.library1 import ClassA, ClassB
```

Comment: -1 Literally from the question: "but of course I don't want to change anything inside ProjectA, it is just a Project that should work either standalone or as a submodule of another project"

Answer (score -1):

Add submodule path to system path in mainB.py
Say your submodule path is "../ProjectB/ProjectA"
sys.path.append(../ProjectB/ProjectA) resolve the issue.